# How can I make set /a X=1, 1 to equal "Potato"?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

So I'm not asking this because it's vital information or anything, I just like programming with batch script when I get bored and wanted to create a "personal assistant" which would open apps for me, so it would make my life a little bit easier instead of searching on my messy computer.

I wanted to include a choice /c MF /m /n Male or Female, so i could send it to my friends to use it too, but I couldn't seem to make it work properlly, as %gender% would get a 0 value instead of M or F.

I tried using set /p but I'd like to know if there is a way to use set to use words instead of numbers, thanks!

(Here's what I wrote in case you need it, i know it may look simple or easy to someone who studied this, but I just do it as a hobbie and rookie "programmer")

```
echo Username
set /p username=
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Gender
choice /c 12 /m /n 1: Male, 2: Female
if %errorlevel%==1 (set /a gender=1)
if %errorlevel%==2 /set /a gender=2)
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Thanks, we will start to create a profile for you...
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
cls
echo Creating profile...
cls
echo Please, insert the name the filesaves will have.
set /p savefile=
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
cls
echo ----------------------------
echo Starting up...
(
echo %username%
)>%savefile%user.sgf
echo %username%
echo ----------------------------
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
echo 50%
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
(
echo %gender%
)>%savefile%gender.sgf
echo %gender%
echo ----------------------------
```

Comment: So many errors.. for starters.. you don't need parens for your `if %errorlevel%` lines.  Why not just assign %errorlevel% to gender?  `if %errorlevel%==2 /set /a gender=2)` is syntactically incorrect. `echo Starting up...` and `timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul` both have odd parens after them that I can't see the purpose for.. honestly.. I can't see the purpose for any of this but you might start with my suggested fixes.

Comment: If it's all for fun & learing, start learning **PowerShell**.

Comment: I concur with @Keith_Miller.  Powershell is a much more enriching experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.. OK.. I get it.  You are learning (Which is REAL COOL)

- Multiple syntax errors fixed.  Please look at what I did differently than you.
- A method that works to go from "1/2" to "male/female".  `set /a` is **JUST FOR MATH**.
- You don't need all of those parens..
- Any time you are evaluating a variable in batch, quote both sides.. `if "bob"=="%myname%" echo Meh namez bob.`  If for some reason your variable is empty, your batch file will give you the finger and exit.

Some ways to make this EVEN BETTER!

- Use ***%UserProfile%\SomeDangDir*** for your "save files". Right now, they drop wherever the current directory happens to be.
- Figure out how to put gender,username, and whatever else into the SAME FILE and pull it back out again.  This will be a challenge with 100 different ways to accomplish it.

`

```
@echo off
SetLocal

echo Input Username:
set /p username=

echo.
echo Input Gender
choice /c 12 /m "1: Male, 2: Female"

if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (set gender=male) else (set gender=female)

echo.
echo.
echo username=%username%
echo gender=%gender%
echo Thanks, we will start to create a profile for you...

timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
cls

echo Creating profile...
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
cls

echo Please, insert the name the filesaves will have:
set /p savefile=

cls
echo ----------------------------
echo Starting up...
echo %username%>%savefile%user.sgf
echo %username%
echo ----------------------------
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
echo 50%

timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo %gender%>%savefile%gender.sgf
echo %gender%
echo ----------------------------

EndLocal
```

Good Luck! :)